# Cisco IPsec VPN tunnel problem

Tags: vlan, vpn, nat, ipsec

I have a problem with VPN configuration. This is the topology I created:

[image]

First updated licenses to make the VPN available:

*license boot module c1900 technology-package securityk9*

**IPsec Router NetworkA configuration:**

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.100.100.2 
!
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.40.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.40.0 0.0.0.255
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
encryption aes 256
authentication pre-share
group 5
!
crypto isakmp key VPN address 200.200.100.1
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN esp-aes 256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto map VPN 10 ipsec-isakmp 
set peer 200.200.100.1
set pfs group5
set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
set transform-set VPN
match address 100
!
interface gigabitEthernet 0/0
 crypto map VPN
!
```

**Ipsec Router NetworkB:**

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.200.100.2 
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.40.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.40.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
crypto isakmp policy 10
encryption aes 256
authentication pre-share
group 5
!
crypto isakmp key VPN address 200.100.100.1
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN esp-aes 256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto map VPN 10 ipsec-isakmp 
set peer 200.200.100.1
set pfs group5
set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
set transform-set VPN
match address 100
!
interface gigabitEthernet 0/0
 crypto map VPN
!
```

**VLAN Router NetworkA**

```
interface gigabitEthernet 0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10 
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface gigabitEthernet 0/1.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 20 
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

**VLAN Router NetworkB**

```
interface gigabitEthernet 0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 30 
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface gigabitEthernet 0/1.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 40 
 ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

**Switch1**

```
interface gigabitEthernet 0/1
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20
!
interface range fastEthernet 0/1-11
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface range fastEthernet 0/11-20
 switchport access vlan 20
!
```

**Switch2**

```
interface gigabitEthernet 0/1
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 30,40
!
interface range fastEthernet 0/1-11
 switchport access vlan 30
!
interface range fastEthernet 0/11-20
 switchport access vlan 40
!
```

I would like VLANs to communicate with each other, however there is a problem with the VPN tunnel.

I think I need to configure NAT but don`t know how.

output "show crypto isakmp sa" is the same on both routers :

```
IPv4 Crypto ISAKMP SA
dst             src             state          conn-id slot status
!
IPv6 Crypto ISAKMP SA
!
```

Comment: Network topology https://prnt.sc/whchw3

Comment: Let's start with some basics.  Please edit your question to include the output of "show crypto isakmp sa" on both routers.  You shouldn't need NAT.

Comment: I added the output. I don't think it looks like it should ;/

Comment: Can router A ping router B?

Comment: Yes they can do it.

Comment: ping from a device on vl 10 to a device on vlan 40 and *show crypto isakmp sa* again.  the VPN tunnel is not being established.

Comment: nothing has changed in output. If it helps i can link .pkt file

Comment: I think you have typos in your access lists *103.168.10.0*

Comment: I do not understand. I do not have this address on my network

Comment: i see it now, my mistake ill edit it and update the result

Comment: Thank you so much for help, the problem was bad ip i`m so blind, all works good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your access-list that was not allowing traffic to enter the VPN tunnel:

```
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.40.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.40.0 0.0.0.255 103.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
```

Note **103.168.10.0** instead of **192.168.10.0**